# Outside promise needs to wait for inner nested promise

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, promise, angular-promise

I've this usecase wherein I wish to do the following :

1. Set metadata in indexDb
2. Iterate over an array of images
3. See if img is already set in indexDb
4. if yes, do nothing, if not, download the img
5. set the downloaded img (as blob) in indexDb
6. Raise all images processed event at the end

ads data :

```
[{
ETag:"",
S3URL:"",
duration:30,
filename:"",
linear-gradient:"",
status:"",
timerRequired:"yes"
}]
```

My code at the moment :

```
 this.Tvlocalforage.setItem('meta', newMeta).then(() => { //Step 1
      for (let idx in ads) { //Step 2
        this.localforage.getItem(ads[idx]['filename']).then(blob => {
           if(!blob){ //Step 3
             LSPromise = imgSrcToBlob(ads[idx]['S3URL'], undefined, 'Anonymous', 1).then((blob) => { //Step 4
              return this.localforage.setItem(ads[idx]['filename'], blob); //Step 5
            });
            LSPromises.push(LSPromise);
           }
        });
      }  
    }).then(() => { 
      if(LSPromises.length) {
        Promise.all(LSPromises).then((data) => {
          this.TvLSkeyCount = LSPromises.length;
          this.fireLoadAssetsEvent(); //Step 6
        });
      } 
    });
```

Problems I am facing :

After the promise for setting metadata is resolved, it straightaway goes to `then()` block and by that time `LSPromises` is `null`. Of course I understand that internal nested promises haven't been resolved yet.

Resolution I tried :

Return LSGetter promises and download images later. this did not work either.

Code I tried :

```
this.Tvlocalforage.setItem('meta', newMeta).then(() => { 
      for (let idx in ads) {
        let p = this.Tvlocalforage.getItem(ads[idx]['filename']);
        LSPromises.push({'promise' : p, 'filename' : ads[idx]['filename'], 'url' : ads[idx]['S3URL']});
      }
  }).then(() => { 
    if(LSPromises.length){
      Promise.all(LSPromises.map(obj => {
        obj['promise'].then(blob => {
          if(!blob){
              imgSrcToBlob(obj['url'], undefined, 'Anonymous', 1).resolve(blob => {
                return this.Tvlocalforage.setItem(obj['filename'], blob);
            });   
          }
        });
      })).then((data) => {this.fireLoadAssetsEvent();});
    }
```

I tried 2 more ways to wrapper up and try to return `promise.all` of download step from inside & on trying to `resolve` that, `return promise.all` of set downloaded images to LS. But it did not work.

Comment: Info : I realised that localforage setItem api fires as is. it can work as a promise but thats optional usage, which means, this.localforage.setItem(k,v) would insert a dummy callback & execute it in line non-promisey style.

Comment: There are other issues you will stumble over. `idx` will not have the value you think it will have at // step 5 if `imgSrcToBlob` is truly async and doesn't resolve right away.

Comment: Yes @JochenBedersdorfer, I realised it pretty soon. we cant ensure correct idx mapping. & last steps which need to set blobs to LS need filename, which comes only from idx.

Comment: Not knowing about the structure of `ads`, this could work better:
`promises = Object.keys(ads).map(idx => this.Tvlocalforage.getItem(ads[idx]['filename])`

Comment: Missing a `return` in the map()....so basically no promises are passed to `Promise.all()`

Comment: `LSPromises` is a `Promise`, not an `Array`

Comment: you can simplify further by returning the Promise array and you also don't need to check `if (LSPromises.length)`

Comment: @charlietfl I tried with many P and Cs. return imgSrcToBlob(...).then(...) did not help as well :(

Comment: Where is `ads` defined?

Comment: @guest271314 I map over LSPromises array & return 'promise' attribute which holds localforage.getItem() promise.  Wouldn't that work?

Comment: @guest271314 I'l add data about ads. 1 min.

Comment: `linear-gradient` should be quoted to avoid syntax error

Comment: Where is LSPromises defined? Is it an empty array?

Comment: @guest271314, all :  Added sample ads data.

Comment: @charlietfl, yes, empty array. function scope.

Comment: Does `this.Tvlocalforage.getItem(ads[idx]['filename'])` return a `Promise`?

Comment: @guest271314, repasting my finding :
localforage setItem api fires as is. it can work as a promise but thats optional usage, which means, this.localforage.setItem(k,v) would insert a dummy callback & execute it in line non-promisey style

So, I am not super sure. digging their docs.

Comment: What was the result of the code that you tried?

Comment: @guest271314 I tried Gunter's version. It worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There might be other errors, but there is a missing `return`:

```
this.Tvlocalforage.setItem('meta', newMeta).then(() => { //Step 1
      for (let idx in ads) { //Step 2
        LSPromises.push(this.localforage.getItem(ads[idx]['filename']).then(blob => {
           if(!blob){ //Step 3
             return /* added return */ imgSrcToBlob(ads[idx]['S3URL'], undefined, 'Anonymous', 1).then((blob) => { //Step 4
              return this.localforage.setItem(ads[idx]['filename'], blob); //Step 5
            });
            // LSPromises.push(LSPromise);
           }
        }));
      }  
     // }).then(() => { 
      if(LSPromises.length) {
        return /* <<<=== */ Promise.all(LSPromises).then((data) => {
          this.TvLSkeyCount = LSPromises.length;
          this.fireLoadAssetsEvent(); //Step 6
        });
      } 
    });
```

If the promise returned from `Promise.all()` is not returned, the caller can not wait for it to complete.

Comment: `LSPromise` is a `Promise`, not an `Array`

Comment: biggest problem in the original code is that a for loop is used, so `idx` won't be valid in step 5

Comment: also need a closure for the `for()` loop

Comment: I made additional changes. I missed a then (`.then(blob =>`)

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Thanks for taking a stab but AFAIK, after setItem('meta') is resolved, it immd goes to 2nd .then() block & by that time LSPromises is null so it does nothing.

Comment: @JochenBedersdorfer  I understand for loop brings in sequential nature & clubbing with promises being asynchronous is a recipe for chaos but my usecase is listed (6 steps) ... any other way to go for it perhaps ?

Comment: I made another update (removed the `.then` line before `if(LSPromises.length) {`

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer trying your version as we speak. will update you with findings on behavior

Comment: Glad to hear :-)

Comment: Thanks much kind sir. You saved my weekend (and perhaps at least 2 weekdays). Marked accepted. Have a nice day :)

Comment: You're welcome. You provided good feedback to be able to work towards a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of the `for()` loop since `idx` will not be what you want it to be inside the promise callback since loop will complete before promises do

Can use map() instead to create the array using a closure

Something like:

```
this.Tvlocalforage.setItem('meta', newMeta).then(() => { //Step 1

  let LSPromises = ads.map(ad => {
    return this.localforage.getItem(ads[idx]['filename']).then(blob => {
      if (!blob) { //Step 3
        return imgSrcToBlob(ad['S3URL'], undefined, 'Anonymous', 1).then((blob) => { //Step 4
          return this.localforage.setItem(ad['filename'], blob); //Step 5
        });
      }
      return null
    });
  });

  return Promise.all(LSPromises).then((data) => {
    this.TvLSkeyCount = data.filter(o => o).length;
    this.fireLoadAssetsEvent(); //Step 6
    // not sure what needs to be returned here
  });

});
```

Comment: Thanks for giving your time. I've a question though, 
Why do we need to return promise.all if there is no functionality needed in setItem('meta').then() now?

Comment: Would only be important if you needed another `then()` in the chain after all have resolved

Comment: Thought so. okay.

Answer (score 0):

I could not test this, but you should try to flatten the nesting, chaining the `then`s at the outermost level. You can use `Promise.all` even more in order to pass the `ad` value through the chain together with the resolved values:

```
this.Tvlocalforage.setItem('meta', newMeta).then(() => // Step 1
    Promise.all(ads.map( ad => // Step 2
        Promise.all(ad, this.localforage.getItem(ad.filename))
    ))
).then(blobs => 
    blobs.filter( ([ad, blob]) => !blob ) // Step 3
).then(blobs =>
    Promise.all(blobs.map( ([ad]) => 
        [ad, imgSrcToBlob(ad.S3URL, undefined, 'Anonymous', 1)] // Step 4
    ))
).then(blobs =>
    Promise.all(blobs.map( ([ad, blob]) =>
        this.localforage.setItem(ad.filename, blob) // Step 5
    ))
).then(data => {
    this.TvLSkeyCount = data.length;
    this.fireLoadAssetsEvent(); // Step 6
});
```

Comment: thats a very interesting approach. I tried Gunter's solution & it solved my usecase while not needing to revamp from ground up. 

Still, very much thanks.